# Can SVN be integrated with authorization service

Tags: svn

I want to configure SVN such that it talks to an external service for authorization. The external service will have its logic to decide the type of access a user has to a path. When a user accesses SVN it should authenticate and then contact the authorization service for the access details - read / write / delete etc. Is this possible and how to configure SVN to implement this. Assume that authorization service is already available.

Answer (score 0):

What type of *authorization service* are you talking about. Subversion doesn't do authorization. Instead, it passes authorization to another service. You can use any service that works with Apache httpd (like LDAP and Active Directory). You can also use SASL over `svnserve` to connect to other services (such as LDAP and Active Directory).

Most of these authorization services are either you have or don't have access to your Subversion repository. That is, once the user is certified, that user will have read/write (i.e. can read, and checkout the files and commit changes). I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that works with LDAP and Active Directory to control write access (that is commit access). Users will still be able to read the repository, but not write to it.

You can (through Subversion itself) control pre-directory access through Subversion itself and even through [Apache httpd](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir).

However, without more information (What type of service are you talking about? What are you trying to restrict? What is your goal? Do you need to restrict both read and write or just write?) it's hard to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks David. I have an application that implements a tree structure. It also implements access control to the tree nodes. The structure in SVN will be identical to the tree in the application. I want to ensure SVN uses the same authorization that the application implements.  So if a user has read access to certain tree nodes in the application then SVN should also restrict access to read for that particular path. If the access is modified in the application to read/write then SVN should auto change the access without manual update to any file in SVN.

Comment: If a user does not have even read access to a node then SVN should not even show that path to the user. So when a user is authenticated then SVN should take the authorization info from the existing application and should show only those paths that the user has at least read access. When user tries to commit, SVN should check with the application whether that user has write access. The important part is when user access change, should not need to modify the access details at both places -- my existing application and SVN

Comment: SVN has its own built-in authorization (that's the per-directory access you describe in the 3rd paragraph). What you're describing in the first 2 paragraphs is *authentication* (you are who you say you are) via another service.

Comment: Are you writing this application? You can have the application do the authorization and talk to SVN for you. Subversion implements an API which could be incorporated into the application.

Comment: Thanks David. What is the API name? I will check if that API works for me. There is already an existing applications. It can authorize. I am trying to integrate the application with SVN as a version control repo. The application currently stores files in blobs and controls access with its authorization rules. By integrating SVN with the application, I will move the files to SVN instead of blobs. But the most important part in the success is that SVN should talk to the application for authorization.

Comment: That is why I am trying to find out if SVN can be configured to send a request to the application to authorize a user's access (read / write / no access etc).

Comment: I think I should also make this clear for why I want SVN to talk to my application for authorization. Once the application integrates with SVN, I want to let users access the files (which are currently in blobs and will be moved to SVN later) directly via SVN (via SVN client or command line) and will not need to go via the current application. Hence it is important that SVN talks to application for authorization.

Comment: Is there a module for httpd or SASL authorization that uses this application? That would be the question. Take a look on the [Apache httpd authentication page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) and see if any of these will work.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've implemented this to allow control over who has read or read/write access is to use the native AuthzSVNAccessFile method from within Apache that David W. alludes to.

The SVN access files I have driven from a separate process that polls LDAP periodically.

In LDAP I have defined a custom objectClass *AuthGroupOfNames* with a couple of attributes ***memberRead*** and ***memberWrite*** which are designed to look much like the normal group attribute *member*.

So an entry for a particular set of SVN repositories looks like so in my LDAP:

```
dn: cn=repo,ou=svn,dc=example,dc=com
cn: repo
objectClass: top
objectClass: AuthGroupOfNames
owner: uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com
description: Example SVN Repository
memberWrite: uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com
memberWrite: uid=user2,dc=example,dc=com
memberRead: uid=user3,dc=example,dc=com
```

In this example users *user1* and *user2* have read/write access and *user3* just has read access.

A cronjob on the SVN server periodically checks the LDAP entry for each configured repository and rewrites the SVN acl file accordingly. For this example the acl file would get written as so:

```
[repo:/]
user1 = rw
user2 = rw
user3 = r
```

Comment: Thanks Liam. I had this solution to update the SVN acl file periodically. But the authorization logic is complex to be deterrent to create all combinations upfront for all users. Also the time lag between change in the application and SVN acl getting updated is not acceptable. Hence I am looking for a way that SVN could send a request to the application to authorize the user (not authenticate) at run time.